# calling db.collection.find() within db.eval()

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have written a javascript function which will get executed inside db.eval() on mongodb on my nodejs platform.

my js function is:

```
function(data){
    var d = {
        vehicle_id:data.vehicle_id,
        timestamp:{
            $gte:data.start_time,
            $lte:data.end_time
        }
    };
    var routeStatus = [];

    db.location.find(d,function(err,result){
            db.result.insert({result});
    });
 }
```

which is minified to an string 'code' to be passed to db.eval()

```
var code = 'function(data){var d={vehicle_id:data.vehicle_id, timestamp:{$gte:data.start_time, $lte:data.end_time}}; db.location.find(d,function(err,result){return result;});}';

db.eval(code,[info],function(err,result){
    log(result);

});
```

the info object contains all required fields getting called by function;

Now main question is db.location.find() is an asynch call so how could i get its result return to callback of db.eval();  ?

if i simply do return result from callback of db.location.find() then i get nothing returned as its being an async call.

Comment: i don't get which data is should go where... but in case you want to execute code after db.location.find das completed, place respective stuff within callback or use mongoose chaining.

Comment: Database operations executed on the server are "synchronous" and do not have callbacks, so the result of `.find()` just returns a cursor "in-line". You likely want `.toArray()` and also probably want to return something as the result of the `.eval()` ( which itself is still async ). That said, you likely really don't want to do this at all, nor should you. Running server side JavaScript like this is fraught with problems, so it's best to just run directly from your client code instead.

Comment: yes, I too agree operations executed on the database server are "synchronous" and hence i tried to get the cursor back as result but .find() was returning a object like it does in our nodejs-mongodb code. Now, why I'm likely to do this is I have an operation which is deals with @NeilLunn huge amount of documents, now in which first I'm supposed to bring all those documents based on some filter and then perform another aggregation call using each document with another  documents from another collection. Now doing this on our code-side brings huge load on RAM than doing on clustered mongo's serv

Comment: @NeilLunn I'll tell exactly what I want to do, i hav set of location based documents stored in one collection called 'location', and have some routes stored in another collection called "routes". Now I want to check all the location points between certain time period whether they were on routes or not using geoNear aggregation. So, there are tow tasks, first bringing all documents from collection and then iterating geoNear aggregation on each location document. I'll b really happy if you suggest me some good and scalable solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

got the answer, thanks to @NeilLunn for giving small but useful tip. the .toArray() worked

simple doing

```
var docs = db.location.find().toArray();
```

worked for me.